# Cannot get data from a js array with Node js

Tags: arrays, node.js, javascript-objects

I have a js object array like this.

```
[  
   {  
      name:"Japanilainen ravintola Koto",
      rating:3.9,
      photo:[  
         {  
            height:2160,
            html_attributions:[  
               "<a href="               https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/110335983983267481647/photos">Hannes Junnila</a>"
            ],
            photo_reference:"CoQBdwAAAMDlivT0nOnYg8jC1txZ3RbfBR59XvKN0WphDbRVUXaUTQclzzaIaXJ8-p7s3x_aG67AUsM_HLNML6pzGl3v_wV2D-eudH_3wy2cB1ROrRgGcGyf4lRuNpE3WwXYbYZu6EK8oEPiJ5B17Lybj-eVbYM2EgVVBgOrUJhsblY1mfxWEhAZ4oHCFakH-hgkbksfGa2uGhQe4aUeOrS2isAir01KUwQ7N3Ce2Q",
            width:2269
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      name:"Kin Sushi Helsinki",
      rating:4.2,
      photo:[  
         {  
            height:2988,
            html_attributions:[  
               "<a href="               https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/103078599092779880596/photos">Stephan Winter</a>"
            ],
            photo_reference:"CoQBdwAAAN4iMumSbQjtRnJIH1AKRdbSfnI02WGh11r1xaVnZl1ohebKp6zpAS4mmJFqTagrIqUJ39kzulVI0sz2UzzfaVdsAFc5f80PnOCzSLqL5gnpsqv90dVJIqUWD3Bcc9TgYPPs3oGwyekkOsmjQ59o9yqdoF5GzrpaKkojhMNLxpfzEhBKpRkA2CzINpUzAAe3e90TGhQ_KbYCmtJYLfVGIu1kZkzQIAwE4A",
            width:5312
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

I get this array above by doing this for each.

```
response.results.forEach((entry)=>{
         var restaurantName = {
          "name" : entry.name,
          "rating" : entry.rating,
          "photo_reference" : entry.photos
        }
        arr.push(restaurantName);
      });
        res.send(arr);
```

And I send the array to my browser so I can see it.
What I am trying to do is to get `photo_reference` from the `entry.photos`
I tried `entry.photos[0].photo_reference` and many more ways and in all of them I am getting a cannot read properly, and now I am not sure how to get that information out.

Answer (score 1):

I edited some of the variable names to make it easier to simulate here, but just `map` the objects in the `photo` arrays to their references, and you'll get an array of photo references.

```js
const data = [  
   {  
      name:"Japanilainen ravintola Koto",
      rating:3.9,
      photo:[  
         {  
            height:2160,
            html_attributions:[  
               '<a href="https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/110335983983267481647/photos">Hannes Junnila</a>'
            ],
            photo_reference:"CoQBdwAAAMDlivT0nOnYg8jC1txZ3RbfBR59XvKN0WphDbRVUXaUTQclzzaIaXJ8-p7s3x_aG67AUsM_HLNML6pzGl3v_wV2D-eudH_3wy2cB1ROrRgGcGyf4lRuNpE3WwXYbYZu6EK8oEPiJ5B17Lybj-eVbYM2EgVVBgOrUJhsblY1mfxWEhAZ4oHCFakH-hgkbksfGa2uGhQe4aUeOrS2isAir01KUwQ7N3Ce2Q",
            width:2269
         }
      ]
   },
   {  
      name:"Kin Sushi Helsinki",
      rating:4.2,
      photo:[  
         {  
            height:2988,
            html_attributions:[  
               '<a href="https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/103078599092779880596/photos">Stephan Winter</a>'
            ],
            photo_reference:"CoQBdwAAAN4iMumSbQjtRnJIH1AKRdbSfnI02WGh11r1xaVnZl1ohebKp6zpAS4mmJFqTagrIqUJ39kzulVI0sz2UzzfaVdsAFc5f80PnOCzSLqL5gnpsqv90dVJIqUWD3Bcc9TgYPPs3oGwyekkOsmjQ59o9yqdoF5GzrpaKkojhMNLxpfzEhBKpRkA2CzINpUzAAe3e90TGhQ_KbYCmtJYLfVGIu1kZkzQIAwE4A",
            width:5312
         }
      ]
   }
]

const arr = []
data.forEach((entry)=>{
  var restaurantName = {
    "name" : entry.name,
    "rating" : entry.rating,
    "photo_reference" : entry.photo.map(x => x.photo_reference)
  }

  arr.push(restaurantName);
});

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Check all of the variable names and property names in your object. That just means you're referencing an invalid name

Comment: everything works if i just add entry.photo, if I add .map and the function you said it crashes.

Answer (score 0):

`entry.photoes` is not defined in your `response.results` object array.. did you mean to access it as `entry.photo` (inside your foreach function) ?

Comment: Yes I did. Can you please help me

Comment: try using debugger... it will show you that you are accessing property with a wrong key